# Disable Flowable/Observable Buffer

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm having issues getting always the last value from combination obtained with a combineLatest operator.

I have 2 hot flowables (a, b) generating **events at high frequency** (an event every 100ms each):

```
Flowable<OrderBook> flowA = sourceA.getObservableOrderBook(value);
Flowable<OrderBook> flowB = sourceB.getObservableOrderBook(value);
```

combined with a combineLatest, which takes almost 300ms to do it's job.

```
Flowable<OrderBookCouple> combined = Flowable.combineLatest(flowA, flowB,        OrderBookCouple::new).observeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
combined.subscribe((bookCouple) -> {
                System.out.println("A timestamp: " + bookCouple.aOrderBook.getTimeStamp());
                System.out.println("B timestamp: " + bookCouple.bOrderBook.getTimeStamp());
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
```

After one execution of the **combiner**, I would like to **process the very last combination** of event generated, meaning (lastA, lastB).

The default behaviour of the combined flow is to cache all combination of events in its own buffer, so that the combined flow is receveing combinations that are very old and this time gap is exploding.

How should I change my code to disable this buffer and receive always the very last combinaton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply `onBackpressureLatest` on both `flowA` and `flowB` and use the [overload of `combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#combineLatest(org.reactivestreams.Publisher[],%20io.reactivex.functions.Function,%20int)) which let's you specify the prefetch amount.

```
Flowable.combineLatest(
    Arrays.asList(flowA.onBackpressureLatest(), flowB.onBackpressureLatest()),
    a -> new OrderBookCouple((OrderBook)a[0], (OrderBook)a[1]),
    1
)
.onBackpressureLatest()
.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread(), false, 1)
```

Unfortunately, there is no overload that takes both a BiFunction and a bufferSize thus you have to revert to casting array elements.

**Edit**

Applying a second `onBackpressureLatest` and limiting the buffer size on `observeOn` should get you closer to the desired pattern, although `combineLatest` is not aimed at this use case. You probably wanted some multi-sample operator.

Comment: I've tried your solution with a simplified example here and it seems that there still is the buffering. The code is available here: [link](https://gist.github.com/Ambros94/06d50869eec77a5758c30c4ed66ab101)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This is working, I updated the gist accordingly. Thank you.